# How can I find all unsed using statements with ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I want to find all unused **using** statements in my Xamarin C# project using Visual Studio and ReSharper.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the unused **using** statements as warnings in ReSharper **Errors/Warnings in Solution** window.

You can open it by,

- Navigating to `ReSharper | Windows | Solution Errors` or,
- By double clicking on the Errors/Warnings link at the bottom right corner of Visual Studio 
  [image: Errors/Warnings link at the bottom right corner of Visual Studio]

  In the appearing window, click on ⚠️ icon to show warnings. If there are unused **using** statements there will be warnings listed. Expand the warnings to find **using** statement related warnings.

  [image: Using statement related warnings]

  Double clicking on the warning will take you to the relevant file. The unused **using** statement can be found in gray colour.

**Note:** Enable *Solution Wide Analysis* and *Reanalyze All* to make sure you want miss anything.